# I have to create hadoop mulitinode setup using hadoop 2.5.1.Is there any documnet avaiable for same?

Tags: hadoop

I have 4 nodes in my cluster. 1 will be master node, 1will be secondary master node and 2 will be slaves. All these nodes have single node setup running. For multinode setup is there any document available?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the apache hadoop version or anything from the distributions like cloudera or hortonworks.

For apache hadoop set up refer this.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/cluster_setup.pdf

Comment: I am using apache version 2.5.1 no other distributions